# Insert data using bootstrap modal in datatables library

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I want to insert data with the help of bootstrap modal. But I've got an error on the action index. So the button I've added couldn't run. Did I make any wrong thing in coding?

**Controller**

```
function user_action(){
        if ($_POST['action'] == "Tambah"){
            $data=array(
                'kodebayar' => $this->input->post('kodebayar'),
                'nama'      => $this->input->post('nama'),
                'harga'     => $this->input->post('harga')
            );
            $this->bpem_m->create($data);

        }
    }
```

**View Of Modal**

```
<div class="modal fade text-xs-left" id="modalpem" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel35" aria-hidden="true">
                                      <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
                                        <form method= "post" id="form_pem">
                                        <div class="modal-content">
                                          <div class="modal-header">

                                          </div>
                                            <div class="modal-body">
                                                <fieldset class="form-group floating-label-form-group">
                                                    <label for="Kode">Kode <span class="required">*</span></label>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="kodebayar" id="kodebayar" placeholder="Kode Pembayaran">
                                                </fieldset>
                                                <fieldset class="form-group floating-label-form-group">
                                                    <label for="nama">Nama <span class="required">*</span></label>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nama" id="nama" placeholder="Nama Pembayaran">
                                                </fieldset>
                                                <fieldset class="form-group floating-label-form-group">
                                                        <label for="projectinput7">Biaya Perbulan <span class="required">*</span></label>
                                                        <div class="input-group">
                                                            <span class="input-group-addon">Rp.</span>
                                                            <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Biaya Perbulan" aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)" name="harga" id="harga">
                                                            <span class="input-group-addon">.00</span> 
                                                        </div>
                                                </fieldset>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" name="action" value="Tambah"/>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        </form>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).on('submit','#form_pem', function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var kodebayar = $('#kodebayar').val();
            var nama = $('#nama').val;
            var harga = $('#harga').val;
            var postData = new FormData(this);

            if(kodebayar != '' && nama != '' && harga != ''){
                $.ajax({
                    url:"<?=site_url('bpem/user_action')?>",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: postData,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    cache: false,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
                    {
                        alert(data);
                        $('#form_pem')[0].reset();
                        $('#modalpem').modal('hide');
                        dataTable.ajax.reload();
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                        //if fails     
                    }

                });

            }
            else{
                alert("Silahkan isikan semua data!");
            }
        });
```

Comment: Where is your form action

Comment: I've edited my question. Please check @SanoojT

Answer (score 2):

You can use `serialize()`

```
    var datastring = $("#form_pem").serialize();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "your url.php",
    data: datastring,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        //var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data); if the dataType is not specified as json uncomment this
        // do what ever you want with the server response
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('error handing here');
    }
});
```

return type is json

EDIT: I use `event.preventDefault` to prevent the browser getting submitted in such scenarios.

Comment: thanks for your answer but i still get the same error. I think something wrong else

Comment: @Fiona can you shows what exact error so I can change edit my answer